# python, TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, inteligencia-artificial

Buenas estoy haciendo un programa en python, y me he encontrado con un fallo en mi código y no logro encontrar cual es el motivo, este es mi código al completo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class LinearDecaySchedule(object): #clase para calcular el epsilon decay
    def __init__(self, initial_value, final_value, max_steps):
        assert initial_value > final_value, 'El valor inicial debe de ser mayor que el valor final'
        
        self.initial_value = initial_value
        self.final_value = final_value
        self.max_steps = max_steps
        self.decay_factor = (self.initial_value - self.final_value) / self.max_steps #valor maximo menos el valor mínimo dividido por el número total de pasos que voy a realizar
        
    def __call__(self, step_num): #los métodos con __name__() son módulos nativos de python
        current_value = self.initial_value - step_num * self.decay_factor #valor inicial menos el número de steps por el factor de decrecimiento, se cuanto le tengo que restar a cada paso
        
        if current_value < self.final_value: #si he bajado mucho del valor final lo corrigo
            current_value = self.final_value
            
        return current_value


epsilon_initial = 1.0
epsilon_final = 0.005
MAX_NUM_EPISODES = 100000
STEPS_PER_EPISODE = 300

linear_schedule = [LinearDecaySchedule(initial_value = epsilon_initial, final_value = epsilon_final, max_steps = 0.5 * MAX_NUM_EPISODES * STEPS_PER_EPISODE)]

epsilons = [linear_schedule(step) for step in range(MAX_NUM_EPISODES * STEPS_PER_EPISODE)]

plt.plot(epsilons)
plt.show()
```

y el problema está en la variable epsilons, que al llegar ahí me salta un error diciéndome: 'list' object is not callable
alguien sabe a que se puede deber esto y como puedo solucionarlo?? muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el error, estaba en la definición de la variable linear_schedule que tiene que ser tal que así:

```
linear_schedule = LinearDecaySchedule(initial_value = epsilon_initial, final_value = epsilon_final, max_steps = 0.5 * MAX_NUM_ESPISODES * STEPS_PER_EPISODE)
```